# Find minimum key in map with Java 8 stream

Tags: java, filtering, java-stream

I'm trying to find a minimum key value in my map. I'm inserting an `AtomicLong` in value portion of the map which is initialized to system time like so:

```
map.putIfAbsent(instr,new AtomicLong(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

Then at a later stage, I want to know the minimum value, here's code snippet:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .filter(key -> key.getKey().getSymbol() == this.symbol)
   .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
   .get()
   .getKey()
```

I get the following error:

```
The method min(Comparator<? super Map.Entry<Instrument,AtomicLong>>) in the type
Stream<Map.Entry<Instrument,AtomicLong>> is not applicable for the arguments 
(Comparator<Map.Entry<Object,Comparable<? super Comparable<? super V>>>>)
```

It was working fine until I changed V part in `Map<K,V>` from `Long` to `AtomicLong` due to thread safety concerns. Please let me know how to implement this functionality with stream. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"I changed `V` part in `Map<K,V>` from `Long` to `AtomicLong` due to thread safety concerns."* why? isn't `Long` as immutable as `AtomicLong` ?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `AtomicLong` is not immutable, so `Long` is *more* immutable.

Comment: @Michael one more reason not to change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`?

You can "implement" your (almost :)) own `Comparator`:

```
.min( (x, y) -> Long.compare(x.getValue().get(), y.getValue().get()) )
```

Comment: Even simpler, perhaps: `.min(Comparator.comparingLong( e -> e.getValue().get() ))`

Comment: Even more complex, perhaps: `.min(Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingLong(AtomicLong::get)))`

Comment: The problem with all of these solutions is that the *comparison* isn't atomic. And without an additional lock, it can't be.

Comment: Thank you so much @kotslon and for your suggestions, really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you so much @Enwired for your suggestions, really appreciate it!

Comment: Thank you all! Going with @kotslon suggestion since I can invoke a descending sort on data as well

Comment: @Michael: if we assume that there could be concurrent changes, it doesn’t matter whether the comparison is atomic or not, even with an atomic comparison, the result could become outdated even while the search for the minimum is still running.

Answer (score 3):

[`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) is comparable to itself because it implements `Comparable<Long>`.

[`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) is **not** comparable to itself because it doesn't implement `Comparable<AtomicLong>`.

This means you cannot use [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--) which takes a `Comparable`.

You could try this instead:

```
.min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.comparingLong(AtomicL‌​ong::get)))
```

Comment: You can use [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue-java.util.Comparator-).

Comment: @shmosel Correct, though perhaps we both should have been explicit about which signature we were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says : `Comparator<Map.Entry<Object,Comparable<? super Comparable<? super V>>>>`

`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` requires that he value be a subtype of `Comparable` and :

- [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) implements `Comparable<Long>`
- [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) did not implement `Comparable<AtomicLong>`

So you cannot use `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` for `sort()`, `min()`, `max()`...

---

You need to provide a `Comparator` by yourself :

- `.min(Comparator.comparingLong(lg -> lg.getValue().get()))` best one
- `.min((lg1, lg2) -> Long.compare(lg1.getValue().get(), lg2.getValue().get()))`